# trouble creating 100vh page with footer and sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a content slider with a chatbox to the side and a footer stuck to the bottom.

Here is a diagram of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

The problem with below code is that the chatbox is the height of the page. I want the chat box to stop at the footer so that it is the height of the page -60px.

And here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #95a5a6;
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 300px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.chatbox {
  background: #bdc3c7;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.footer {
  background: #2c3e50;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="chatbox"></div>
  <div class="wrapper-inner">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjxsyve7/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only adding this:

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

In your code the `chatbox` div has height 100% of the body. But if you set `position: relative;` to it's parent(.wrapper) it will have height 100% of it's parent.

This is an easy way to do this with flex:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #95a5a6;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;  
}

.chatbox {
  background: #bdc3c7; 
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.footer {
  background: #2c3e50;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="chatbox"></div>
    <div class="wrapper-inner">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Trouble is that its parent, wrapper, is 100vh so if I do that then the chatbox goes over the footer: https://jsfiddle.net/bjxsyve7/5/

Comment: Ah, makes sense!

Comment: Like the answer by Michael_B? I need to do a tutorial on flexbox.

Comment: Yes it is the one. And it is very very good for you to learn flex box

Comment: To learning flex, Firstly read this basic article: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp then read this advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties

Comment: Thank you so much for those links! I have my work cut out this evening.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified version using only flex and `calc()`:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
}

.chatbox {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #95a5a6;
}

.footer {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #2c3e50;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatbox"></div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjxsyve7/6/)

Comment: Awesome and clean, how would I vertical-align the content though?

Comment: Thanks for going above and beyond!

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS calc() to achieve this. Add this min-height: calc(100% - 60px) to .chatbox. For more info about [calc()](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #95a5a6;
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding-left:300px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.chatbox {
  background: #bdc3c7;
  min-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  top:0;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.footer {
  background: #2c3e50;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="chatbox"></div>
  <div class="wrapper-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```